# How to make a Squeak class from scratch?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I want to make a simple program in Squeak that calculates the distance between a couple of points, but I would not like to use the class Point that is already defined. So far I have the following:

[image]

The getter and setter methods of x and y have been auto generated:

x
^ x

x: anObject
x := anObject.

and the distance method I programmed is the following:
[image]

```
distance:aPoint
    "comment stating purpose of message"

    |dx dy |
    dx:=aPoint x - x.
    dy:=aPoint y - y.
    ^ (dx*dx+dy*dy) sqrt.
```

now I open a workspace and try to print out the results:

```
obj1:=PointS new.
obj1 x:3 y:4.
obj2:=PointS new.
obj2 x:5 y:6.
d:=obj1 distance obj2
UIManager default inform: 'Converted amount: ',d.
```

but the result I get is the following:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the following:

```
obj1 x:3 y:4.
```

With this:

```
obj1 x:3; y:4.
```

Basically, you are sending the message `#x:y:` but you don't have a method with that name. Instead you have a method `#x:` and another method `#y:`, so you need to make two separate calls to the same object (which is done with the *cascade* operator (`#;`).

Answer (score 3):

**Watch the precedence**

In your method `distance: aPoint` you are computing the Pythagorean distance as

```
(dx*dx + dy*dy) sqrt
```

While this formula is correct in the usual mathematical notation and in most programming languages, in Smalltalk it will work differently. In fact it will produce the same as

```
((dx*dx + dy)*dy) sqrt,
```

which is not what you want. The reason for this is that in Smalltalk both `#*` and `#+` are binary operators with the same precedence. Thus, you should write

```
((dx*dx) + (dy*dy)) sqrt
```

instead, or equivalently

```
(dx*dx + (dy*dy)) sqrt
```

since you only need to make sure that `dy*dy` is the argument of `#+`.

A more elegant way to achieve the same is

```
(dx squared + dy squared) sqrt.
```

Also, if you take a look at the `Point` class you will find the `#r` method from polar coordinates that would give the desired result if you write

```
(dx @ dy) r.
```